# How to reach 3 VM under machine with 1 public IP

Tags: windows, networking, hyper-v

I have one machine (machine A) with 3 VM on Hyper-V (Windows server Datacenter 2019).
Machine A is reached by one public IP.
How can the virtual machines be reached directly from an external network?

Answer (score 2):

You can not.

YOu need a reverse proxy through it. What you ask is identical to having 3 cars with the same number plate.

A reverse proxy will be able to distribute incoming traffic by some rules.

But it is not "direct", so it is a no as answer.

Comment: OP doesn't need a reverse proxy per se, could also use NAT on the host to the VM internal network, for example. But the question was for "directly", so yes, you are correct with "no".

Comment: NAT is equivalent to direct nowadays. This is done on the network ip layer and it is very common to use NAT for some kind of direct access from external networks. Thought in that case you need PAT in addition wich only works with specific ip protocols which are port based and You cannot use same external incoming port for the services on same local port.

Comment: "NAT is equivalent to direct nowadays" - no, it is not. It is a step that must be documented as an interim network device with configuration and from experience with large companies I can tell you it is all BUT direct - takes separate paperwork to a seprarate team.

Comment: If NAPT were equivalent to direct routing, NAT traversal techniques to work around broken end-to-end connectivity would not be necessary. Not the same.

Answer (score 2):

IPv6.

Perhaps a significant project if you have not started. However, forget about IP address scarcity when you can allocate /64s.

Edit: regarding concerns v4 only users cannot access, mitigate those in your network design.

- v6 WAN and Internet access
- mobile data plans on v6 providers
- 6in4 tunnel
- remote access VPN with v4 endpoint

To run a public service, or if client networks are behind on their v6 deployment and will not use transition methods, you would still want v4. Which does not solve your not enough IP address problem.

But if you control the network, you can access over IPv6 anywhere in the world.

Comment: Maybe a choice, but i am thinking the user will not have the ability to set up an ip4t6 or ip6t4 translator

Comment: Regarding v4 only users, see edit.

Comment: Next days i 'll try your solution. I can access to all machines